# Access DB cant return focus to inputbox

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am using an Access Db to export some information to an Excel Workbook. I am using an input form to add dates to the query that creates the sheet. If I create 1 sheet the export works. If I create more than one sheet once the query goes to the second sheet the focus stays on the excel spreadsheet. If you enter a date it goes on cell A1 of the spreadsheet instead of the input box.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Public Function ExportSpreadSheet(path As String)

Dim xlPath As String, I As Integer
Dim DB As Database 
Dim myrs As Recordset ' Create a recordset to hold the data
Dim strSQL As String 
Dim myExcel As New Excel.Application ' Create Excel with Early binding
Dim wrkbk As Object 
Dim wrksht As Object 
Dim targetworkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim FileRange, name As String
Dim extraChar, queryForTransfer, searchSheet As String
Dim objXL As Object
Dim objAC As Object
Dim x As Integer
Dim myFileName As String
Dim sheetDate As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim amtofsheets As Long
Dim s As Long
Dim ctlCurrentControl As Control
Dim strAnswer As String

On Error GoTo Err_ExportSpreadSheet

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    xlPath = path

    amtofsheets = InputBox("Enter amount of sheets", "Amount of Sheets")

    Set DB = CurrentDb 
    Set objAC = CreateObject("Access.application", "")
    For s = 1 To amtofsheets

      strAnswer = Forms("Browse1").txtFileSelection
      sheetDate = InputBox("Enter Trade Date of Entries ex 10/04/2017", "Trade Date")

        If s = 1 Then Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.application", "")
        If s = 1 Then objXL.Visible = True
        If s = 1 Then objXL.DisplayAlerts = True
        If s = 1 Then Set targetworkbook = objXL.Workbooks.Add 
        'Add worksheet if need more than three worksheets

         strSQL = "SELECT FXOpenDeals.city, FXOpenDeals.[As of Date], FXOpenDeals.[Cnt Pty name], FXOpenDeals.[deal number], FXOpenDeals.value, FXOpenDeals.ccy1, FXOpenDeals.[ccy1 amt], FXOpenDeals.ccy2, FXOpenDeals.[ccy2 amt], FXOpenDeals.[unrealized G/L_PV] " _
            & " FROM [A1-Internal_Customers] INNER JOIN FXOpenDeals ON [A1-Internal_Customers].[counterparty number] = FXOpenDeals.[counterparty number] " _
            & " WHERE FXOpenDeals.[trade] = #" & Format(sheetDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#" _
            & " ORDER BY FXOpenDeals.[Cnt Pty name];"

        Set myrs = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL) 

        If amtofsheets = 1 Or amtofsheets = 2 Then
            For I = 1 To targetworkbook.Worksheets.Count
                sheetName = "Sheet" & I
                Select Case sheetName
                    Case "Sheet2"
                        targetworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
                    Case "Sheet3"
                        targetworkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
                End Select
            Next I
        End If

        If s > 3 Then
        With targetworkbook
            .Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.name = "Sheet" & s
        End With
        End If

        'Get spreadsheet headers
        x = 0
        For Each Field In myrs.Fields 'RS being my Recordset variable
            targetworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & s).Range("A1").Offset(0, x).Value = Field.name
            x = x + 1
        Next Field
        targetworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & s).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset myrs
        targetworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & s).Columns("A:K").AutoFit
        'Name Worksheet
        sheetName = Format(sheetDate, "mm-dd")
        targetworkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & s).name = sheetName

    Next s

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    myFileName = "Internal Customer FX Deals"
    targetworkbook.SaveAs FileName:=xlPath & myFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
    targetworkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    If Not objXL Is Nothing Then
    objXL.Quit
    objXL.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set objXL = Nothing
    Set myrs = Nothing
    End If

    MsgBox "Internal Customer FX Deals Data successfully Exported", vbOKOnly
Exit_ExportSpreadSheet:
Exit Function
Err_ExportSpreadSheet:

Err.Clear
Resume Exit_ExportSpreadSheet

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are doing a whole lot of work for nothing. There's not need to automate Excel unless you want to do some formatting. Simply export the query to Excel via TransferSpreadsheet. Instead of the input box, use a parameter in the query, or better yet, a small form with a textbox.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "yourQueryName", "FileName", True, "SheetName"
```